# How to layout html CSS in this way?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a simple problem to layout a web page,

i need:

1st) header = width:100%; heigth:100px.(every time above - except heigth is less 500px and scroll)

2nd) body = min-heigth:500px; heigth: 100%; width:960px;

3rd) taskbar = width:100%; heigth:90px(every time bottom - except height is less 500px)

live preview: http://templates.cms-guide.com/42161/

Comment: Why not right click and view source? :)

Comment: i did it 100 times, download and check it too, but i couldn't figure. out, i undrestand dynamic back groundbut not this!

Comment: [media queries](http://mediaqueri.es/)

Comment: @lante I would say javascript. Try to disable and you will see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not particularly pretty (from a CSS point of view) but should give you a starting point.

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/UBBxH/2/)

HTML

```
<section>
    <article></article>
    <header></header>
    <footer></footer>
</section>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}
header, footer, article {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
header {
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    top:0;
}
footer {
    height:90px;
    bottom:0;
    background:green;
}
section {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    min-height:590px;
    background:grey;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    min-width:960px;
}
article {
    padding-top:100px;
    padding-bottom:90px;
    margin:0;
    width:960px;
    background:blue;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: nice simple and clear, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>
        <title>WebSite</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="body"></div>
        <div id="taskbar"></div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#header{
    max-height: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

#body{
    min-height: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 960px;
}

#taskbar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    max-height: 500px;
}
```